# URI.getAuthority() always returning null:80 in unit test

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-cloud, spring-test

I'm writing unit tests for a load balancer, the goal is to be able to filter out certain services based off its URI. However, the test always fails because it doesn't get the right URI at all! Here's the test class:

```
public class FilteringDiscoveryClientTest {
   private static DiscoveryClient mockClient;

   @BeforeAll
   public static void setUp(){
      SimpleDiscoveryProperties properties = new SimpleDiscoveryProperties();
      Map<String, List<DefaultServiceInstance>> instances = new HashMap<>();
      
      DefaultServiceInstance testInstance1_1 = new DefaultServiceInstance();
      testInstance1_1.setUri(URI.create("http://my.service.id.1/1"));
      testInstance1_1.setServiceId("my.service.id.1");
      DefaultServiceInstance testInstance1_2 = new DefaultServiceInstance();
      testInstance1_2.setUri(URI.create("http://my.service.id.1/2"));
      testInstance1_2.setServiceId("my.service.id.1");
      DefaultServiceInstance testInstance2_1 = new DefaultServiceInstance();
      testInstance2_1.setUri(URI.create("http://my.service.id.2/1"));
      testInstance2_1.setServiceId("my.service.id.2");
      DefaultServiceInstance testInstance2_2 = new DefaultServiceInstance();
      testInstance2_2.setUri(URI.create("http://my.service.id.2/2"));
      testInstance2_2.setServiceId("my.service.id.2");
      instances.put(
         "my.service.id.1",
         Arrays.asList(testInstance1_1, testInstance1_2)
      );
      instances.put(
         "my.service.id.2",
         Arrays.asList(testInstance2_1, testInstance2_2)
      );

      properties.setInstances(instances);
      SimpleDiscoveryClient client = new SimpleDiscoveryClient(properties);

      mockClient = client;
   }

@Test
   public void testGetServicesFilteringOutSingleService() {
      FilteringDiscoveryClient client = new FilteringDiscoveryClient(
         mockClient,
         i -> !i.getUri().getAuthority().equals("my.service.id.1")
      );
      
      assertFalse(client.getServices().contains("my.service.id.1"), "list of services not expected to contain service 1");
      assertTrue(client.getServices().contains("my.service.id.2"), "list of services expected to contain service 2");
   }
}
```

the assertFalse fails because the `i.getUri().getAuthority()` returns null:80 instead of what the actual URI being passed is. It all seems to be set right according to the debugger during `setup()`. Any ideas where my test has gone wrong? Should I be setting URIs differently to begin with?

Edit: maybe I should add what the FilteringDiscoveryClient looks like

```
public class FilteringDiscoveryClient implements DiscoveryClient {
   private final DiscoveryClient delegate;
   private final Predicate<ServiceInstance> filter;

   public FilteringDiscoveryClient(DiscoveryClient delegate, Predicate<ServiceInstance> filter) {
      Assert.notNull(delegate, "delegate must not be null");
      Assert.notNull(delegate, "filter must not be null");

      this.delegate = delegate;
      this.filter = filter;
   }

   @Override
   public String description() {
      return delegate.description();
   }

   @Override
   public List<ServiceInstance> getInstances(String serviceId) {
      return delegate.getInstances(serviceId).parallelStream().filter(filter).collect(Collectors.toList());
   }

   @Override
   public List<String> getServices() {
      return delegate.getServices().parallelStream().filter(s -> !getInstances(s).isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe not an optimal solution but at least a workaround? Turns out that using `.setUri()` calls upon the overridden one within the class `DefaultInstanceService`, which does not set it the way I expected it to. It creates a new URI every time a new DefaultInstanceService is made from what I can tell, and that seems to not take the URI I give within `setUri()`. So I created constructors like so:

```
 DefaultServiceInstance testInstance1_1 = new DefaultServiceInstance("http://my.service.id.1/1", "my.service.id.1", "my.service.id.1", -1, false);
      
      DefaultServiceInstance testInstance1_2 = new DefaultServiceInstance("http://my.service.id.1/2", "my.service.id.1", "my.service.id.1", -1, false);
      
      DefaultServiceInstance testInstance2_1 = new DefaultServiceInstance("http://my.service.id.2/1", "my.service.id.2", "my.service.id.2", -1, false);
      
      DefaultServiceInstance testInstance2_2 = new DefaultServiceInstance("http://my.service.id.2/2", "my.service.id.2", "my.service.id.2", -1, false);
```

my tests work now but there is one small kink when trying to get the path, which I expected to be /2. Instead, no path is set at all because the `setUri()` within DefaultServiceInstance never sets a path explicitly, so it's always just an empty string. I cannot do calls like `instance.getUri().getPath()` because it will just give me an empty string back. To get to the "/2" I'm looking for I have to do `instance.toString()` and get it from there. All in all, not a great workaround but it's progress! If anyone has a better idea in the future I'd love to know.